# Unable to compile a c application that reads smartcard

Tags: c, smartcard, pkcs#11, hsm, opensc

I am trying to compile an example c application that is using pkcs#11 to finds all
the private keys on the token, and print their label and id, but getting following errors

```
/tmp/ccAqQ7UI.o: In function initialize':
pkcs11_example1.c:(.text+0x8e5): undefined reference to C_Initialize'
/tmp/ccAqQ7UI.o: In function `get_slot':
```

The example is taken from [here](http://www.NLnetLabs.nl/publications/hsm/examples)

compilling by using following command;

```
 `gcc pkcs11_example1.c -o slots -L /usr/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so`
```

I am not sure which library i should link after -L. 
Can anyone guide how to compile this and are there some libraries required to link.

Comment: ...did you link the necessary libraries? If not, then that would be your problem.

Comment: You should add the actual link command to a question like this. But, you are missing either `-Lpath_to_library` or `-lnameoflibrary` or both from the link command, or have wrong path or library name there.

Comment: @hyde & nneonneo I edited my question and added the command  but I am not sure what libraries are required to be linked

Answer (score 2):

C_Initialize and other 60+ functions with "C_" prefix are cryptoki functions defined in [PKCS#11 specification](http://pkcs11interop.net/rsa-pkcs11-2.20/pkcs-11v2-20.pdf). They are usually implemented in standalone library provided by HSM vendor. Looking at your code samples I would say that you need to directly link also PKCS#11 library or you can modify the code to dynamically load PKCS#11 library in runtime with [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) and then acquire pointers to all cryptoki functions via the C_GetFunctionList call. You can also take a look at [pkcs11-logger the source code](https://github.com/jariq/pkcs11-logger/blob/master/src/init.c#L56) for an example on how to do that.

Comment: Commands like "pkcs15-tool -c" and "opensc-tool" are working on my system but I don't have any standalone library provided by HSM vendor. I am compiling the code using "gcc pkcs11_example1.c -o slots -L /usr/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so". Do I need to have some additional libraries or I already have them as I mentioned before that pkcs commands are being recognized by my system. p.s OS is Linux.

Comment: @user3591981 Ok I see. Your PKCS#11 library opensc-pkcs11.so exports only C_GetFunctionList PKCS#11 function which provides pointers to all the other PKCS#11 functions. See my [previous answer about this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22769105/3325704library) as it fully applies to your problem.

Comment: I simplified the code and now just trying to initialize as in your privious answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22769105/3325704library, but when i try to compile `gcc -g -Wall -L /usr/lib/pkcs11/opensc-pkcs11.so  pkcs11_hello.c -o hello` it gives `pkcs11_hello.c:33: undefined reference to `C_GetFunctionList'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`. When i nm /usr/lib/pkcs11/opensc-pkcs11.so it says no symbols and i could not see any C_GetFunctionList in pkcs11.h. How can i send my code, opensc-pkcs11.so and pkcs11.h to you for review if possible for you.

Answer (score 0):

The link command you give, `gcc pkcs11_example1.c -o slots -L /usr/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so`, is wrong.

- `-L` takes just path, which is added to paths where libs are searched from, but `/usr/lib` is default so you don't need this switch at all.
- You are missing `-l`, which takes the library name without *lib* prefix or *.so* suffix, so looks like you need `-lopensc-pkcs11`.

So, first make sure your library file really is `/usr/lib/libopensc-pkcs11.so` (note *lib* prefix!) possibly with verion numbers following. Then change build options so link command becomes

```
gcc pkcs11_example1.c -o slots -lopensc-pkcs11
```

Comment: In comments of other answer you talk about different path, so you may need *-L /usr/lib/pkcs11*